# wordpress - how can I block email sending by role?

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I have an educational Wordpress site where students have the role 'child' and adults have the role 'subscriber'. I need to prevent emails being sent to the 'child' users (by Woocommerce - but I think they are sent via the mail function in Wordpress).

Is there a line I can add in functions.php to stop mail being sent to specific roles?

Thanks in advance

Maria

Comment: you can use get_users( 'role' );. if user is subscriber sent mail

Comment: what type of emails are being sent to the `child` users that you don't want to send?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Subscription and order emails currently go to all user roles but I don't want any emails going to children.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be possible to adjust the email recipients via a filter in the [`get_recipient()` method](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/64d0be16a4b26159d6441992e272ec5d03f65775/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php#L283).

```
/**
 * get_recipient function.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function get_recipient() {
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_' . $this->id, $this->recipient, $this->object );
}
```

Let's take for example the new order email. Here's it's [`trigger()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/c6dae2b2866dfd42db2b092a426d01d1f3b49892/includes/emails/class-wc-email-new-order.php#L61-78) method:

```
/**
 * trigger function.
 *
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */
function trigger( $order_id ) {
    if ( $order_id ) {
        $this->object       = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $this->find['order-date']      = '{order_date}';
        $this->find['order-number']    = '{order_number}';
        $this->replace['order-date']   = date_i18n( wc_date_format(), strtotime( $this->object->order_date ) );
        $this->replace['order-number'] = $this->object->get_order_number();
    }
    if ( ! $this->is_enabled() || ! $this->get_recipient() ) {
        return;
    }
    $this->send( $this->get_recipient(), $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
}
```

Specifically

`if ( ! $this->is_enabled() || ! $this->get_recipient() ) {`

which says if there is no recipient then the email won't send. Also `$this->object       = wc_get_order( $order_id );` tells us that the `$order` object is passed to the `get_recipient_$id` filter.

The id of the new order email is "customer_completed_order" as shown in the [class constructor](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/c6dae2b2866dfd42db2b092a426d01d1f3b49892/includes/emails/class-wc-email-new-order.php#L27) for the email.

**SO**, putting that all together we can filter the recipient for new order emails:

```
add_filter( 'so_29896856_block_emails', 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 10, 2 );
function so_29896856_block_emails( $recipient, $order ) {
    if( isset( $order->customer_user ) ){
        $user = new WP_User( $customer_user );
        if ( in_array( 'child', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
           $recipient = false;
        }
    }
    return $recipient;
}
```

However, this assumes that the recipient is a single string (if an array it would kill *all* the recipients and not just the child... though by the default the new order email is sent to the billing email address.

Also, note that I didn't test this at all, so your mileage may vary.